# How to color in an SVG file with multiple lines?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Forgive me for i'm pretty new to SVG files, but i basically have about 1000 lines worth of code from an image that I'm using as an SVG to fill in only specific parts with colors.

So my question is, how do i target the space between them? So for instance:

```
<g id="LINE">
<line class="st0" x1="34.3" y1="73.3" x2="17.4" y2="83"/>
</g>
<g id="LINE_1_">
<line class="st0" x1="30.5" y1="67" x2="13.8" y2="76.6"/>
</g>
```

how would I tell it that i want the space between 'line' and line_1' to be a specific color?

[image: simple paint image]

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "space between". Could you add an image?

Comment: Make a Shape and use the fill="#abc" property?

Comment: @Bsalex The image is pretty complex when it's coded into an SVG but ill do a simple paint image and edit the post with that.

Comment: @Blackbam But are shapes defined if they're made with lines? For example if you made a box with 4 lines, how would you target the area within it?

Comment: Use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/polygon or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/path

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with lines, you should construct you shape from polygon, polyline, rect and then use fill=color to color it

Comment: Oh.. this thing is so complex, i thought uploading it as an SVG and changing colors that way would be the way to go.. Would you happen to have another suggestion for showing different colors on an image rather than uploading the image itself 10x over again?